# Problem in showing that this determinant is greater than zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

In one class the teacher showed us one problem about determinants that himself could not solve, and I tried solve the problem too, but I didn't had success even in the $3$ by $3$ case, I'm very curious to know the solution of this problem, so that is the reason I'm posting here. The problem is the following:

If I have a real square matrix $A$ of order $n$ in which:

1) Each diagonal member $a_{ii}>0$;

2) If $i \neq j$ then $a_{ij} \leq 0$;

3) For each colum $j$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij} > 0$;

Then how to conclude that $det(A)>0$ ?

Comment: This is not true unless we have the strict inequality $\sum_i a_{ij} > 0$.  If the inequality holds, then we can show that the determinant is positive using the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)

Comment: A counterexample to the problem as presented:
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2}
$$
note that $\det(A) = 0$

Comment: Oh, thank you for correcting the claim, I will read about this Theorem.